# RSpec: Method test will not pass unless method called therein is also tested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails

I'm new to testing with RSpec and FactoryBot so any help would be appreciated.  I've encountered an odd case with the following code/tests.

Here are my models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bars, dependent: :destroy

    def update_baz_count(baz_count)
        most_recent_bar.update_current_baz_count(baz_count)
    end

    def most_recent_bar
       bars.last
    end
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo

  def update_current_baz_count(new_baz_count)
    self.baz_count = new_baz_count
    self.save
  end
end
```

And here are my tests:

```
describe Foo do
  # This test passes
  describe "#most_recent_bar" do
    let!(:foo) { create(:foo) }
    let!(:bar) { create(:bar, foo: foo) }

    it 'should return the most recent bar' do
      expect(foo.most_recent_bar).to eq(bar)
    end
  end

  describe '#update_baz_count' do
    let!(:foo) { create(:foo) }
    let!(:bar) { create(:bar, foo: foo) }

    it 'should call update_current_bar_count on the storage history' do
      ## Test will NOT pass unless following line is uncommented:
      # expect(foo).to receive(:most_recent_bar).and_return(bar) 
      expect(bar).to receive(:update_current_baz_count).with(1)
      foo.update_baz_count(1)
    end
  end
end
```

The issue is that in my `#update_baz_count` test passing is contingent on  setting an expectation regarding the `#most_recent_bar` method.  As noted above, my test for `#most_recent_bar` passes, and it feels redundant to be making assertions about the performance of that method outside of its dedicated test.

So, *why* is the success of my test contingent on the line `expect(foo).to receive(:most_recent_bar).and_return(bar)`?

Comment: Can you share the error message, when the spec fails?

Comment: nvmnd, I see it now - check out my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set up the mocking behavior on the object available in specs:

`expect(bar).to receive(:update_current_baz_count).with(1)`

But! In your production code, the same row will be fetched from db:

`bars.last`

And AR will create a new object for you, which have no idea that you mocked it in your specs.

You can check it out like this:

`expect(bar.object_id).to eq foo.most_recent_bar.object_id`

Which will fail.

If you want to do it without mocking, do something like this:

```
it 'should update update_current_bar_count on the storage history' do


  expect{ foo.update_baz_count(1) }
    .to change { bar.reload.field_that_baz_count_updates}.from(0).to(1)
end
```

So instead of checking that the method was called, check the effect the calling of the method had on the "world".

Comment: Interesting!  Thanks so much for your response!